# Integrating Yelp API v2 into iOS

Tags: ios, yelp

I am trying to use Yelp API, and I have received ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, Token, and TokenSecret from the developer site.

I tried to follow the sample code from GitHub, and I came up with two questions.

**Question 1**

Is it mandatory to use CocoaPod for OAuth? If not, can I create my own HTTP request?

**Question 2**

If I can create my own HTTP request, how is the URL structure for Yelp Authentication?

Ex. https://host_address/...

I am new to OAuth, so it will be very appreciated if you can help.

Thank you.